# How do I use pre batched data and data of different shape in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

So I have gathered data that is a list of tensorflow tensor

```
List=[tensor1,tensor2,....tensor_n]
```

These tensor have different shapes:

```
tf.shape(tensor1)=(batch_size1,1,9)
tf.shape(tensor2)=(batch_size2,2,9)
tf.shape(tensor_n)=(batch_size_n,n,9)
```

so the data is batched so that second dimension of every entry that is equal is batched together.

how can I modify the

```
model.fit(input,output,batch_size,epoch)
```

function to respect my preselected batches and is it possible to train a model with different shapes of input in each batch?

Comment: So the batches you fit the model is preselected one in your list tensors right? From the description of your question I'm not sure what could be the problem.

Comment: I am not sure how I can realise this would I go like 
`for i in List:
     
     model.fit(i,output_i)
`
This would mean I call the fit function for every batch again. Is this the optimal way to solve my problem?

Comment: I would also try using [model.train_on_batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#train_on_batch)

Comment: It depends on your model. Some layers support dynamic shape (RNN, attention)